# ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable Huggingface

Tags: tensorflow, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, huggingface-tokenizers

Hi I am following the Huggingface course for [Question Answering](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter7/7?fw=tf).

I built my own Dataset and all the features are present and I get the exact same results up until fitting the model.
There I get the above error.
After some research it seems this is caused by not having the columns in the correct order.

The tokenizer does output it in a different order and I changed it, but neither the order in the course nor the order of the tokenizer seem to work.

Can someone think of another issue?
I don't have the Data Collator as it's deprecated now.
Token Type Ids are commented out because the tokenizer does not return them.
I'm using `"distilbert-base-cased-distilled-squad"` because I just want to try and that seems like the fastest (smallest) model.

```
tf_train_dataset = train_dataset.to_tf_dataset(
    columns=[
        "attention_mask",
        "end_positions",
        "input_ids",
        "start_positions",
        #"token_type_ids",
    ],
    shuffle=True,
    batch_size=4,
)
```

Thank you very much!

edit: I get the same error with the model from the tutorial.